# How can i make it automatic ? And how can i sort each group of indexs in the List?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the method i have in a new class:

```
public ExtractImages(List<string> FirstTags, List<string> LastTags, List<string> Maps, string LocalFileDir, string UrlsDir)
        {
            localdir = LocalFileDir;
            counter = 0;
            imagesSatelliteUrls = new List<string>();
            imagesRainUrls = new List<string>();
            int startIndex = 0;
            int endIndex = 0;
            int position = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < Maps.Count; i++)
            {

                    string startTag = FirstTags[i];
                    string endTag = LastTags[i];
                    startIndex = Maps[i].IndexOf(startTag);
                    while (startIndex > 0)
                    {

                        endIndex = Maps[i].IndexOf(endTag, startIndex);
                        if (endIndex == -1)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        string t = Maps[i].Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex + endTag.Length);
                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            imagesSatelliteUrls.Add(t);
                            counter++;
                        }
                        if (i == 1)
                        {
                            imagesSatelliteUrls.Add(t);
                        }
                        position = endIndex + endTag.Length;
                        startIndex = Maps[i].IndexOf(startTag, position);

                    }
                    if (i >= 0)
                    {
                        imagesSatelliteUrls.Insert(0, "Group 1");
                    }
                    if (i == 1)
                    {
                        imagesSatelliteUrls.Insert(counter, "Group 2");
                    }
                    //imagesSatelliteUrls = imagesSatelliteUrls.OrderBy(q => q).ToList();
            }
        }
```

In the end imagesSatelliteUrls that is List contain for example 70 indexs inside.
For example:

```
index[0] "Group 1"
index[1] some link here ... http...
index[2] some link here ... http...
.
.
.
index[30] some link here ... http...
.
.
.
.
index[45] "Group 2"
index[46] some link here ... http...
.
.
.
.
index[70] some link here ... http...
```

The variable Maps contain 7 indexs. 
So there will be 7 itertions/loops.
I need somehow to make it automatic so it will add a new string like: "Group" + i
For each group of links.

I can keep reseting the variable counter or use another int variable and count it in the if (i == 1 )
then in if (i == 2)

And then to make if ( i == 2) then imagesSatelliteUrls.Insert(newCounter, "Group 2");

But instead writing for each loop a new IF statement how can i make it all automatic ?
So in each Maps itertion/loop it will add a new "Group" + i

The next thing is this line that im not using now:

```
imagesSatelliteUrls = imagesSatelliteUrls.OrderBy(q => q).ToList();
```

If i will use this line now it will put all the Groups in the beginning of the List.
I need somehow that it will sort the indexs(links) for each Group. And not sort all the List imagesSatelliteUrls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add each group for each `i`, it's so simple that you can do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Maps.Count; i++) {
  //must place this at the very beginning of your loop
  imagesSatelliteUrls.Add("Group " + (i+1));
  //....
}
```

Comment: The OP accepted it and I guess that is OK. But I am not sure what has this to do with ordering the elements of each group on account of the given group. My answer seems pointless and thus should be deleted... (PS: my first intention was proposing to write the group name as a pre-step for ordering, which was the question here, but I thought it was "too aggressive" with respect to the OP's approach... I am seriously speechless)

Comment: @varocarbas in fact the OP's question is very confusing for anyone not reading carefully, I also had to read it very carefully for several times and I understand that his code can be simplified much like as I posted.